# take screen shot of div html canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

Hi I am able to take the screen shot of the div using the code:

```
<div id="manequinn" >
<div class="product-preview" id="save">
            <div class="product toggleMe" id="top">
                <div id="front" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/front/front.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="sleeves" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/sleeve/sleeve.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="cuffs" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/cuff/cuff.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="placket" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/placket/placket1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="cuffs_button" class="mann">

                    <img src="img/buttons/button2/sleeve2_button.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="collar_band" class="mann">

                    <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/collar/collar_band.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="colar" class="mann">

                    <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/collar/collar1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="pockets" class="mann">

                    <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/pocket/pocket1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttons" class="mann">

                    <img src="img/buttons/button2/placket_button.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="back" class="toggleMe">
                        <div id="front" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/front/front.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                    </div>
                    </div>

            </div>

            </div><!-- /demo --><input type="submit" value="Save Image" onclick="capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="safe.php" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

This is my script

```
<script>

function capture() {
    $('#manequinn').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
        $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        //Submit the form manually
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
});
}
</script>
```

And this is the php code to save the image safe.php:

```
<?php
define('DIRECTORY', 'new/');
$content = file_get_contents(''.$_POST['img_val'].'');
$count = 1;
     foreach(glob('./new/*') as $filename)
    {
    $count = $count +1;

    }
file_put_contents(DIRECTORY . '/image' . $count . '.png', $content);
header('Location: index2.php');
?>
```

I am able to save the image for one div but when i apply loop to the div for multiple images of the same div using for loop.
What should i do to make it save multiple images.

I also added loop for the div

```
<?php for($l=1;  $l<=4;  $l++)
                    { ?>
<div id="manequinn" >

    <div class="product-preview" id="save">
        <div class="product toggleMe" id="top">
            <div id="front" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/front/front.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="sleeves" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/sleeve/sleeve.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="cuffs" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/cuff/cuff.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="placket" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/placket/placket1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="cuffs_button" class="mann">

                <img src="img/buttons/button2/sleeve2_button.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="collar_band" class="mann">

                <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/collar/collar_band.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="colar" class="mann">

                <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/collar/collar1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="pockets" class="mann">

                <img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/pocket/pocket1.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                <div id="buttons" class="mann">

                <img src="img/buttons/button2/placket_button.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="back" class="toggleMe">
    <div id="front" class="mann"><img src="img/fabric/fabric_1/front/front.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline;">
                </div>
                </div>

        </div>
</div>

<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to capture screen shot of multiple divs and send it in single form or their own separate form?

Comment: I want to save all the images generated in a folder

Comment: hmmm..............

Comment: Kindly help me how to make it work